# Linking crosshair on multiple charts in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyjs, r-highcharter

I'm using Shiny + Shinydashboard.  My charts are interactive and created with highcharter.  I have multiple charts that share the same x-axis (dates).  I want to link the charts so the crosshair position is the same x-axis on all charts and moves on all charts linked.

I found this JS snippet on Highcharts, but it's not possible to use with Highcharter.  https://www.highcharts.com/demo/synchronized-charts.

**Snippet showing the three highcharts I want to link**

**ui.R**

```
    tabItem(tabName = 'namespace',
            #' graph for message trends
            fluidRow(
              box(
                title = 'Active Namespaces',
                highchartOutput('active_namespace_graph', height = '300'),
                width = 4
              ),
              box(
                title = 'Channel Volume',
                highchartOutput('message_volume_graph', height = '300'),
                width = 4
              ),
              box(
                title = 'Campaigns Created',
                highchartOutput('campaign_count_graph', height = '300'),
                width = 4
              )
            )
```

**Charts**
[image]

Comment: It looks like there are multiple table that are split by month. You may look into some of the parsing functions and import the data by month

Comment: Example on the link is a one chart with 3 sections. Synchronisation can be done like that using the `hc_yAxis_multiples` however its a bit more coding to do it when the charts are separate

Comment: @PorkChop  Yea, but I was hoping to synchronize 3 separate charts.  Is this possible?

Comment: I know there is a similar feature in `dygraphs` but you would have to Write `JS` to do it in `highcharter`